# How to dynamically delete rows from table after time passes?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I know that i can do that with CRON but there are a lot of issues with these method. I have a Entity "Events" and when $eventDate <= Date (NOW) it will be deleted dynamically. I'm using PHP Framework Symfony2.

Comment: just do it when someone loads the page if you don't want to do it with a cron

Comment: I was about to propose the same solution as @DarkBee

Comment: Doing the check on page load seems to be the easiest solution, but it is a bit static and a row will not be 'deleted' before the page is (re)loaded again. If you want it to be 'really dynamic' you would have to use Javascript - is it an option for you?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you want to use cron? Another approach is using queues that allow to use delayed messages (something like Beanstalkd, it has a lot of bundles for Symfony) -- but obviously it's more complicated than cron.

Answer (score 0):

What issues are with a cron? You can create a symfony command that do what you want and call it from a event listener on the request or from a cron.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a symfony command that delete the Event when $eventDate <= Date (NOW) and you can add a cron to run the command every X time